# c# trying to make two colors in progress bar at run time

Tags: c#, silverlight, colors, progress-bar, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to develop c# web application using silverlight-5.

I have to create a progress bar which will have two colors green(up to some percentage) and then Red which will be done dynamically by some data manipulation in c#.

I want to make it of two colors by some percentage of green and rest red (percentage will be decided at run time). I read several documents but were complicated for me to understand.

Could someone please help me to write it's code in c# ? (Or if this progress bar don't change color by value taken at runtime then could some one please write a simple code to create a custom progress bar changing color at run time according to the changing values at run time). Would be a big help.Thanks

**Probably i guess the code will be written in c# because in xaml the colors display ratio will be fixed but it's percentage of these 2 colors has to change according to data values obtained at run time in c# code**

Note: I am developing webapplication using silverlight and c#.

so code has to be written in body like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace B
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Poor attempt and research effor[t .........](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/styling-wpf-volume-meter.html)

Comment: @Sayse But they were difficult to understand for me. I want something simple to understand.

Comment: @Sayse It's a WPF application i am working in silverlight applicationn

Comment: From what I can tell its the exact same, even the documentation for "silverlight progress bar style" has an example of how this is done

Comment: @Sayse butthere is nothing written in c#. because the color will be decided in c# code at run time. Could you please help me there ?

Comment: @Sayse it's not possible in silverlight i guess all options are for Windows forms. If my search is poor then please prove it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Foreground` property to use a `LinearGradientBrush` that is adjusted dynamically in your code-behind.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ThresholdIndicator"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_thresholdBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(){
                           MappingMode = BrushMappingMode.Absolute};
    GradientStop colorLeftOfThreshold =  new GradientStop(){
                                         Color = Colors.Green,
                                         Offset = 1};
    GradientStop colorRightOfThreshold = new GradientStop(){
                                         Color = Colors.Red,
                                         Offset = 1};
    m_thresholdBrush.GradientStops.Add(colorLeftOfThreshold);
    m_thresholdBrush.GradientStops.Add(colorRightOfThreshold);
    ThresholdIndicator.Foreground = m_thresholdBrush;
    ThresholdIndicator.SizeChanged += (s,e)=>UpdateThresholdBrush();

    //this.ThresholdRatio is your dynamic green/red threshold
    this.ThresholdRatioChanged += (s,e)=>UpdateThresholdBrush();

    UpdateThresholdBrush();
}
private LinearGradientBrush m_thresholdBrush;
private void UpdateThresholdBrush()
{
    m_thresholdBrush.EndPoint = new Point(GetX(), 0);
}
private double GetX()
{
    return this.ThresholdRatio * ThresholdIndicator.ActualWidth;
}
```

Note that I only change the `EndPoint`, the two GradientStops are always at the endpoint position.

[Edit] Ok, I can see you struggle with `this.ThresholdRatio` and the changed event, this should do:

```
public double ThresholdRatio
{
    get { return (double) GetValue( ThresholdRatioProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( ThresholdRatioProperty, value ); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ThresholdRatioProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "ThresholdRatio", typeof(double),
    typeof( MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(HandleThresholdRatioChanged) );

private static void HandleThresholdRatioChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainPage)d).RaiseThresholdRatioChanged();
}

private void RaiseThresholdRatioChanged()
{
    var handlers = ThresholdRatioChanged;
    if (handlers!=null) handlers(this,EventArgs.Empty);
}

public event EventHandler ThresholdRatioChanged;
```

Comment: thanks let me check it, Will come soon to mark it once if it works :)

Comment: what is this ThresholdRatioChanged and ThresholdRatio they seems different ? and not initialized anywhere. TThanks

Comment: @ user234839: you said you have some kind of (dynamically changing) ratio that determines the exact position when the color should switch to red...
...so I decided to assume the existence of `this.ThresholdRatio` ...and a corresponding `ChangedEvent`.

Comment: you mean this "thresholdRatioChanged" must be declared like this : public event Action thresholdRatioChanged; at the top (because compiler dont recognize it gives error).

Comment: Yes. Here is a [page on msdn about Events in SL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have to use a progressbar, then I think you'de be better of making a custom representation, for example with an itemscontrol and then defining a datatemplate for that, something like this:

XAML

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ic"
                      BorderBrush="Black" 
                      BorderThickness="2" 
                      Background="Gray" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource test1}" 
                      Height="100" 
                      Width="400">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

DATA TEMPLATE

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="test1">
            <TextBlock Background="{Binding Color}" 
                       Text="{Binding}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="2">
                <TextBlock.Width>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiMarketConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="MarketShare"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="ic" Path="Width" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Width>
                <TextBlock.Height>
                    <Binding Path="Height" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
                </TextBlock.Height>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: but c# behind it ? The percentage of this green color and red color bar will change at run time. How i will handle that in c# ?

Comment: @ Pompair: `MultiBinding` is not available in SL.
How is this `ItemsControl` supposed to be a suitable replacement for a ProgressBar?

Comment: @Martin you are right even it don't support "System.Drawing". Could you please give me some alternative to achieve for progress bar with 2 colors according to the value assign dynamically?